# Issue in Excel Output while using SXSSF Transformer with JXLS (>=2.7.0)

Tags: excel, apache-poi, jxls, sxssf

I've observed that the static cells are getting erased in output when I'm using SXSSF transformer to transform and apply the area as per the comments from template.

I'm using `JXLS 2.11.0` and `JXLS-P0I 2.11.0`.

Moreover I've noted that such behavior is observed in versions newer that `JXLS 2.7.0` with `SXSSF Transformer`

This behavior exists with fixed set of pattern i.e. in which static cell is either to left or right of iterated cell.

[Sample Template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pjoBZ.png)

**Output** : [JXLS 2.11.0 Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uZpIR.png)

Note that A3 cell("Manager") from Template is erased.

Any comments/lead/resolution if bug would be highly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

This issue will be resolved in JXLS - 2.12.0
[Info](https://github.com/jxlsteam/jxls/issues/153)
[PR Fix](https://github.com/jxlsteam/jxls/pull/159)

Comment: It's awesome that you link to the solution. But please include what the solution is in your answer. :-)